# IE9 input setSelectionRange() after paste not working

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, html-input

I have to manually set the caret-position to 0 in an input-field (in the input-event). I need to support >= IE9. Even in IE9 this works ok as long as I do normal input (pressing keys on my keyboard). But as soon as I use copy&paste, the caret isn't set to the desired position (0).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open IE in IE9-Mode
2. Open fiddle below
3. Type into the input-field (works ok, the caret gets set to 0)
4. Paste something into the input-field (fails, the caret gets set to the end of the pasted text)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wv61t7k5/7/

**Code**

```
<input type="text" />

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function(){
  this.setSelectionRange(0,0);
});
```

Comment: Why don't you add a focus Event as well?

Comment: The element is already focused when i paste something in it, correct? I tested it and it made no difference. Could you provide some code, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Funny. First I thought IE9 maybe would not fire the event on pasting, but it does. No idea why this would not work.

However, you could use the `keyup` event. This is definitely not as good as using `input` but will work in IE9.

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    if (e.key != 'Left' && e.key != 'Right' &&
      e.key != 'Shift' && e.key != 'Control') {
            this.setSelectionRange(0,0);
      }
});
```

To still be able to select text by keyboard, you'd have to exclude some keys.

Here is an [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wv61t7k5/13/).

#### Update

Well, this still does not work if the user pastes text by using mouse and context menu. Happily IE knows the `paste` event. Unhappily there is no after paste event, so you'd end up using a `timeout`:

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function(e){
    this.setSelectionRange(0,0);
});
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('paste', function() {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        that.setSelectionRange(0,0);
  }, 100);
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/autromwo/).

Comment: I guess that's the best I can hope for. But I think pasting data by "mouse and context menu" is very rare anyway. And even then it's usable. I changed your solution a bit: It is fast and sexy in modern browsers now but it also will work in IE9 (by using the keyup-event). Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wv61t7k5/19/. For feature readers: This is only a POC and you have to check for more keys in the keyup-event (arrows etc).